# If neutrinos are majorana fermions, does that mean any massive, weakly interacting majorana fermions will decay into neutrinos easily?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, dark-matter

In particle physics, Dirac fermions are protected by conserved quantum numbers (electric charges, color charges, etc.). As a result, Dirac fermions can only annihilate with their antiparticles, and massive Dirac fermions (muons, top quarks, etc.) can only decay into their lighter counterparts. Majorana particles OTOH can annihilate with themselves, which prohibits them from carrying any conserved quantum numbers. As a result, the stability of majorana fermions are protected by quantum number conservation which prohibits their decay into Dirac fermions (e.g., $\chi \rightarrow e^{-}\gamma$), and conservation of angular momentum which prohibits single majorana fermions from decaying into bosons or fermion pairs (e.g., $\chi \rightarrow \gamma\gamma$ or $\chi \rightarrow e^{-}e^{+}$). And because majorana fermions don’t interact via electromagnetic or strong interaction, their chance of annihilating with each other is extremely low. This may explain the virtually unchanged abundance of dark matters (which are suspected as majorana weakly interacting massive particles (WIMP)) since the early universe.

However, if neutrinos are majorana fermions, things are totally different. Because majorana neutrinos don’t carry any conserved quantum numbers, decay into neutrinos (e.g., $\chi \rightarrow \nu\gamma$) are not prohibited by conservation laws. And because WIMP experience weak interaction, the decay kinetics should be fast enough to eliminate all majorana WIMP in today’s universe. Does that mean if neutrinos are majorana fermions, there can’t be stable majorana WIMP, and the dark matter must be made of something else (sterile neutrinos etc.)?

Comment: Waitwaitwait: no matter what, neutrinos have no charge, so they don't couple to photons directly, no?

Comment: But WIMP should if they are massive enough (near the electroweak scale).

Comment: Majorana particles with charge??

Comment: Higgs bosons are chargeless, but can decay into two photons.

Comment: This is through an indirect, loop (triangle anomaly) coupling, properly suppressed. Remember that BR?

Comment: Even though the BR is very low, the partial half live is still very short, which can’t explain the extreme stability of dark matters.

Comment: This depends on the couplings of the WIMPS you posit. You must specify these couplings before declaring there cannot be stable solutions.

Comment: As long as WIMP carry weak charges, I don’t think the coupling is much different than leptons and quarks. Particles can only carry integer amount of charges (you never see a particle with 0.1 elementary charge). Unless the massive majorana particles only interact via gravity (such as sterile neutrinos), the decay should be fast enough to deplete all dark matters.

Comment: But the lepton-number violating term you may be positing is not consistent with the Yukawa couplings of the quarks and the leptons. You are assuming a sterile species, no? In any case, you might finesse your question.